# How to use 'ANY' function with JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I currently use JOOQ to get data from postgresql DB. Then I have faced a problem to get data which data-type is array type.

Current condition is like below:

Table schema is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE favorites (
    id int,
    items    varchar(100)[]
);
```

Sample data is:

```sql
INSERT INTO favorites (id, items)
    VALUES (1, '{orange, lemon, banana}');
INSERT INTO favorites (id, items)
    VALUES (2, '{apple, grape}');
```

To get first data, SQL is like:

```sql
SELECT id, items FROM favorites WHERE 'orange' = ANY (items);
```

But, I cannot create sql like above with JOOQ.

```java
Connection connection = ...;
DSLContext context = DSL.using(connection, ...);
List<Table> table = context.select().from(TABLE).fetchInto(class.TABLE);
```

Can I use ANY function with JOOQ? 
If it is possible, how can I create it with JOOQ. 
If not, is there any other ways to get the same result with JOOQ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
List<TableRecord> table = context
    .selectFrom(TABLE)
    .where(val("orange").eq(any(TABLE.ITEMS)))
    .fetch();
```

The above query uses [`DSL.any(Field<T[]>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any-org.jooq.Field-)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is Case-sensitive, isnt it?

Comment: Is it possible to be not case-sensitive and partitial-match like: For example, using `likeIgnoreCase("OraNge")` or `like("%ang%")` ?

Comment: @tsuxkky: Hmm, that's quite a different query. Mind asking a new question?

Comment: Never mind.  I already asking a new question.  Please check this one also if you don't mind.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557902/how-to-use-like-function-to-select-array-of-strings-with-jooq